# How to align text inside a spinner to center in javafx?

Tags: javafx, fxml, desktop-application

I have two spinners that show time in hrs and mins each. However I would like to have  the numbers show up in the center of its textfield.[screenshot_of_current_state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuxSH.jpg).

Also its not an android app. Its a normal javafx based desktop app.(I'm saying this cause other similar questions are based around android and xml's)

Also I'm new around here and to programming as a whole. So I could be wrong about some things.

Comment: Try HansSolo `TilesFX`. He has a clock tile in there. https://github.com/HanSolo/tilesfx

Comment: Sure, will do. But for now I'm trying to keep it basic as I'm still learning stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> factory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 23);
Spinner<Integer> hoursSpinner = new Spinner<>(factory);
hoursSpinner.editorProperty().get().setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

The *editor* property wraps a [TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html).
`TextField` has an *alignment* property.

Comment: Viola! It works like a charm. Thanks. Would've never found out about this otherwise.